# How to share my app link on button click on Android app?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-intent

I have tried like following code to get share button:

```
final Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
           intent.setType("text/plain");
           intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, url);

           try {
             startActivity(Intent.createChooser(intent, "Select an action"));
           } catch (android.content.ActivityNotFoundException ex) {
             // (handle error)
           }
```

But this is giving me list of share options `ON START` when I start my app.

I want it when I click on "share button" like below image.

How can I modify my code?

[image]

Comment: Have put write this code on share button click

Comment: but how can I make that same button i'm not getting :(

Comment: It's called the Share Action Provider. Google it and you will find the answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I resolved it with following code.

```
@Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu)
    {
        //add item menu 
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
        //share new code
         MenuItem shareItem = (MenuItem) menu.findItem(R.id.menu_item_share); 
         ShareActionProvider mShare = (ShareActionProvider)shareItem.getActionProvider();

         Intent shareIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
         shareIntent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
         shareIntent.setType("text/plain");
         shareIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, "text to share");

         mShare.setShareIntent(shareIntent);

         return true;
    }
```